# Issues while running with BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

We are testing with STORAGE_WRITE_API to insert data into BigQuery. We've seen several errors/warnings in our Dataflow pipeline(written in Java). It might work well in the beginning, but eventually the system lag would be increasing, it would stop processing any data from PubSub and the unacked messages piled up.

One common warning is:

```
Operation ongoing in step insertTableRowsToBigQuery/StorageApiLoads/StorageApiWriteSharded/Write Records for at least 03h35m00s without outputting or completing in state process
  at java.base@11.0.9/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:885)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1039)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1345)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:232)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.RetryManager$Callback.await(RetryManager.java:153)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.RetryManager$Operation.await(RetryManager.java:136)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.RetryManager.await(RetryManager.java:256)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.RetryManager.run(RetryManager.java:248)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWritesShardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn.process(StorageApiWritesShardedRecords.java:453)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWritesShardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
```

Other exceptions we've seen:

`Got error io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Stream is closed`

`Got error io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: ALREADY_EXIST`

```
PodSandboxStatus of sandbox "..." for pod "df-...-pipeline-...-harness-qw4j_default(...)" error: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: No such container
```

Code sample:

```
        toBq.apply("insertTableRowsToBigQuery",
                BigQueryIO
                        .writeTableRows()
                        .to(String.format("%s:%s.%s", PROJECT_ID, DATASET, table))
                        .withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getTriggeringFrequency()))
                        .withNumStorageWriteApiStreams(options.getNumStorageWriteApiStreams())
                        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a production issue related to connection being stuck after streaming 10MB which has been fixed. If you try again, it should work.

Comment: Thanks Stephanie. Is there a way we can configure to make sure it's less than 10MB? I guess you mean the max request size https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#write-api-limits ?

Comment: This is a common question actually. From the API perspective, we cannot retry on this error since it's a hard limit so we expect users to handle this and keep it under 10MB. This limit existed also for the insertAll API and since we're using a compact binary format over-the-wire for the Write API, there should be a bit more allowed. Let me check with folks familiar with Dataflow to see if there are other things we can do from the Dataflow side.

Comment: BTW, if insertAll API -- STREAMING_INSERTS has the same hard limit, how would the API and us as developers handle it if request > 10MB